# Create tables in a database using a script file

Tags: postgresql, batch-file

I have a batch file which installs PostgreSQL and then creates a database called mydb.

Now I want to execute another .pgsql file from that batch file which will create few tables into that database.

How can I call that .pgsql file from the batch file?

Comment: Use psql: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, i'm able to restore the dump file using psql command.